# ERROR This job is stuck because the project doesn't have any runners online assigned to it. even though i have added runner and it is alive

Tags: gitlab, cicd

Despite of the fact runner is alive. Why this error is coming

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to either configure the runner to run untagged jobs, or tag your job to use the runner.

To configure the runner to run untagged jobs:

> 1. Go to the project’s Settings > CI/CD and expand the Runners section.
> 2. Find the runner you want to pick untagged jobs and make sure it’s enabled.
> 3. Click the pencil button.
> 4. Check the Run untagged jobs option.
> 5. Click the Save changes button for the changes to take effect.

Ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/13.12/ee/ci/runners/#use-tags-to-limit-the-number-of-jobs-using-the-runner

To add a tag to your job:

```
job:
  tags:
    - ci
```

Ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags